# C program Babylonian Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

The following code works fine. However, while initialising `x`, if I put `x=n/2` instead of `x=n`, I don't get a valid result for inputs less than 4. Can someone please explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

float squareRoot(float n) 
{ 
   float x = n;                  //x= n/2;
   while (x - n/x > 0.00001) 
    { 
        x = (x + n/x) / 2; 

    } 
    return x; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    float n; 
    float y;
    printf("enter the number to find the square root of:");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    y=squareRoot(n);
    printf("Square root of %f is %f\n", n, y); 
    getchar(); 
}
```

Comment: Well, suppose you chose n to be less than 4, n<4 and x = n/2 -> x < 2. First time when checking while condition, you get n/2 - n/(n/2) = n/2 - 2, which for values less than 4 is negative, so basically you do not iterate. A solution is to use fabs in loop condition.

Comment: @vasile_t: so, basically, this would have been seen when run in a debugger. Or even with a basic `printf` inside that while loop...

Comment: `|x - n/x| > 0.00001` does not work fine for small nor large numbers.  The terminating condition should be relative, not absolute for FP numbers.

Comment: Unrelated: never use `float` without an exceptionally good reason for it. "My teacher told me to" is not an exceptionally good reason... "My teacher told me to, after we talked about the differences between `float` and `double`" approaches an exceptionally good reason.

Comment: regarding: `while (x - n/x > 0.00001)`   This is comparing a `float` with a `double`  as the literal `0.00001` is a `double`.  Suggest: `while (x - n/x > 0.00001f)`  Note the trailing `f` makes the literal a `float`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%f",&n);`  1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (scanf family returns the number of successful 'input format conversions'  so any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) This does not consume the trailing newline in `stdin`, so the call to `getchar()` will immediately return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while (fabs(x - n/x) > 0.00001)`

Because for values of `n` less than `4`, the while loop never gets executed, `n/2 - n/(n/2)` being less than `0`.

Comment: Thanks.. it was bugging me so much